# JetBrains Rider "go to source" does not work

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, rider, go-to-definition

I usually use pycharm/idea for python and java etc and I often whack <kbd>F4</kbd> to get to the declaration of a class or method. Intellij calls this "go to source" in the keymap editor.

I just recently installed Rider to do some c# work and immediately found <kbd>F4</kbd> to not work. The key is still bound correctly but I end up having to use <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> to accomplish the same thing which I thought was super weird and annoying. <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> accomplishes the same thing in Pycharm and IDEA from what I can tell.

Does anyone know why F4 doesn't work in Rider for c# and how I might go about correcting this? Preferably without having to rebind keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both <kbd>CTRL+B</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> works on Rider. But they're available in different contexts. And you need to use both to move around the code.

<kbd>CTRL+B</kbd> works when the cursor is on a symbol in the code (i.e. inside the editor). <kbd>F4</kbd> works when viewing quick documentation, in Debugger pane, i.e. outside the editor.

Comment: It does work with CTRL+Left Mouse or with Middle Mouse too.

Comment: Why does F4 work in Pycharm in the same context you described for CTRL+B but not in Rider?

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda F4 doesn't take me to source like Ctrl+B in Pycharm. It works the same way as Rider. Are you sure you don't have a custom shortcut defined in Pycharm? Or using a different keymap?

Comment: I'm using the default Windows bindings in pycharm, If my caret is in a method call, F4 takes me to the definition. CTRL+B takes me to the same place. I'm using the "Intellij" keymap in rider

Comment: >You say F4 doesn't work, but it does work - Answer Accepted